# Sonarqube: unit test coverage for multiple language project

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage

I have a multiple module maven project containing both Java and Javascript language. I have only java unit test till now, and generate unit test coverage through jacoco. It is running well but I would like to understand more about the unit test coverage number.

Currently I have 125k java code and 175k javascript code, and the unit test line coverage is 44%. Since I have only java unit test, the coverage should be all contributed by java. When I drill down to the line coverage, SonarQube tells me I have 32k uncovered lines, and the uncovered lines are all java code.

Then I am a little confused: If 44% is only about java coverage, I should have 125k * 56% = 70k uncovered lines of java code; if 44% is for all languages, I should have already cover all my java code because (125k + 175k) * 44% > 125k. So which number should I trust? Obviously I have not covered all lines of java code, hence I tend to believe 44% coverage is only for java code, but I have no idea why uncovered lines is 32k instead of 70k.

P.S. I use SonarQube 4.5.1 with java plugin 2.6.

Best Regards,

Comment: Sherlock Holmes: "If you eliminate everything else (as impossible), whatever is left must be the truth".

Comment: how much SLOC (sloccount) value you see for your main source code (i guess in java). Unit tests won't matter i.e. how many LOC or in which languages(Java/Groovy) or script (JS) tests are written.

Comment: Arun, could you please let me know how to view SLOC? My concern is how to understand the figures SonarQube shows: LOC for java 125k, LOC for javascript 175k, UT line coverage 44% ( I have only UT for java code), uncovered lines (when drilling down by clicking lines coverage link in UT section) 32K...

Comment: Interestengly enough, when I added unit tests info from javascript files to my c# project, it shows now only javascript unit tests count (previously it was c#, and I think sonarqube still importing them, but just don't count anymore). But as soon as I don't have coverage for javascript, it still comes from c# info.